# Mongo match returns all data if for one condition is true

Tags: mongodb, match

I've got a problem with mongo query. I want to take all the data in given time. eg. From 2019-01-01 to 2019-01-10. But I see that if even one element matches the condition mongo is returning me whole data.

```
db.production.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$machine_name",
            "array": {
                "$push": {
                    "value": "$value",
                    "type": "$variable_name",
                    "date": {
                        "$dateFromString": {
                            "dateString": "$datetime_from",
                            "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "array.date": {
                        "$gt": ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z")
                    }
                },
                {
                    "array.date": {
                        "$lt":ISODate("2019-01-02T23:59:59Z")
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]);
```

Here is schema: 
[image: mongo schema]

It should return only data in a given time period

Comment: Can you please share your schema or sample MongoDB document.

Comment: I've imported it from csv. Here is example:
<code>
id,"machine_name","variable_name","datetime_from","datetime_to",value
1,"4x2 brick mould","PRODUCTION","2018-01-01 00:05:00","2018-01-01 00:10:00",2094
2,"4x2 brick mould","SCRAP","2018-01-01 00:05:00","2018-01-01 00:10:00",130
3,"4x2 brick mould","CORE TEMPERATURE","2018-01-01 00:05:00","2018-01-01 00:10:00",77
</code>

Answer (score 0):

Project the data you want to view. For example in when we use find query

```js
db.collectionname.find({
  fieldname: "value"
},
{
  fieldname: 1
})
```

So , here first `{}` matches and second `{}` projects only that value.

Depending on your schema if there are conditions if this value is present in some documents not in other the use conditions like `"fieldname":{ $exists: true}}` in match condition.

Comment: Ok but it's only projections. Calculations will be still done on all data.